# change num key to string key [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

```
Array ( [0] => aanneville [1] => cjaouen [2] => ebaltarejo [3] => izaalberg [4] => jfmallot [5] => matcheanauto [6] => matchfullauto [7] => pcouturier [8] => relisabeth [9] => scataldi [10] => tcouturier [11] => tlansiaux [12] => valves )
```

I want this :

```
Array ( 'login' => aanneville  => cjaouen 'login' => ebaltarejo)  //etc.
```

Because this code won't work, and I don't undersand why ??

```
                    <?php 


                            $tab = array("valeur 1", "valeur 2", "valeur 3");
                        //print_r($tab);    

                  ?>

    <script> 

                    var tab= <?php echo $tab; ?> ;
                    console.log(tab);

            </script>
```

Comment: `'login' => aanneville  => cjaouen` This makes absolutely no sense! What do you want to do?

Comment: a simple transfer into another container with new keys should suffice, keys must be unique though

Comment: Is there any logic in the changes you want to make?

Comment: Seems a little bit "for the sake of it" question...

Comment: I want this for using in javascript code like an json format

Comment: cause I can't use this  : {"0":"aanneville","1":"cjaouen","2":"ebaltarejo"} ....

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to change the nuleric key in string ( 'login' ) in a foreach

Comment: The real question is how I can send my array in a javascript code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not exactly  understand your problem ,if you want to  make a table of login, you can proceed as well :

```
$login['login']=array('anneville', 'cjaouen', 'ebaltarejo','etc..' ) ;
```

or

```
$login=array( 'login' =>array (
                         'log1' => 'anneville',
                         'log2' => 'cjaouen', 
                         'log3' => 'ebaltarejo',
                         'logx' =>  'etc..' 
                         ) 
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, array keys must be unique.But if you want to change num keys to string keys, you can use array_combine()